# Java generics: How to cast to (T extends Comparable<? super T>) without raw-types

Tags: java, generics, casting, warnings, raw-types

I wonder whether it is possible to cast a non-Comparable to something so that it matches the method parameter T which has template type `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`, like the `Collections.sort()` method

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)
```

Suppose I somewhere have a reference to list of non-Comparables and want to invoke that method by casting like this:

```
List<E> foo = new List<E>(a);
Collections.sort( /* magic cast */ foo);
```

I can do this if I cast to `(List<? extends Comparable>)`, but this generates a warning that I am using raw-types (Comparable without template types in this case). Let's say I want to avoid using raw-types or even suppressing them via `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")` (e.g. to preserve backward compatibility and avoiding raw-types).

Is it possible to avoid using raw types by casting to `(List<? extends Comparable</*something*/>>)` and what would it be that "something" (unchecked cast is acceptable)?

**EDIT**: This example is just to illustrate the point. Actually I do not have a Comparable nor do I want to sort anything, but I just need to dynamically check whether something is of some type (Comparable in this example) (via instanceof) and then pass some argument to a method which has template arguments similar to the `Collections.sort()` method.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding something, but what you are trying to achieve doesn't really seem to make sense. If `E` does not implement `Comparable`, what is the point of trying to pass a list of these to `Collections.sort`? Surely you will just get a class cast exception at runtime?

Comment: i think public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list) means the same as public static <T> void sort(List<Comparable<T>> list). Dont? You just want to be sure that all objects in list implements Comparable rigth?

Comment: And if it doesn't implement Comparable you could use the sort-method, which takes a Comparator.

Comment: Can't you specify your type parameter E as: <E extends Comparable<E>> ?

Comment: @Peter: let's say I want to first check whether it is instance of Comparable and then cast. This makes sense if I want to sort something on the best-effort basis.

Comment: @Puce: I am not trying to sort actually. This is just a simple example which does not make sense, but in my case, it makes sense.

Comment: Maybe you would get better answers if your example made sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast it to

```
Collections.sort((List<Comparable<Object>>) list);
```

This will not give "rawtype" warnings. Just one "unchecked cast" warning (which you will get anyway.)

Judging from what you mentioned in the **EDIT**, ultimately you want to do something like this?

```
if(!list.isEmpty() && list.get(0) instanceof Comparable){
    List<Comparable<Object>> cmprList = (List<Comparable<Object>>)list;
    Collections.sort(cmprList);
}
```

Comment: As you can't really typecheck whether some specific object is comparable to some specific other object (without using reflection looking at their compareTo methods, or actually invoking this compareTo-method), this seems to be actually the best possibility.

Comment: `list.get(0) instanceof Comparable` will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if called on an empty list.

Comment: @Daniel No, it works as expected (tested on Oracle JDK7 just in case). If list is empty, the `list.get(0)` will not be executed when list is empty, because the `!list.isEmpty()` expression will be `false` and the `&&` in Java is evaluated lazily.

Comment: @rodion: I stand corrected -- not sure how I've missed that though.

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly not possible. `Collections.sort` requires the `Comparable` in order to call the `compareTo()` method. So in your oppinion, what should happen when sort get's a collection of non-comparable objects?

It might be that you want to use something like a default ordering, based on the references for example. But such a thing does not exist implicitly. Though, it can be implemented. But I doubt that this is what you want? So why do you want to sort the list in the first place? And how should these elements be sorted?

Comment: I don't want to sort actually. This is just an example which everyone is familiar with, to make things easier to explain.

Answer (score 1):

This will compile in Eclipse:

```
List<?> foo = new ArrayList<Object>();
Collections.sort((List<Comparable>) foo);
```

You will get a "Type Safety: Unchecked" warning that you can suppress with this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

That will let you call sort. Is that what you're looking for? No guarantees it will be safe at run time, of course.